# Enum algorithm of lattice reduction algorithms (eg, HKZ, BKZ)

Tags: combinatorics, matlab, integer-lattices

I'm trying to understand and implement the BKZ lattice reduction algorithm using MATLAB. However, the center vector $c_t$ in line $8$ of the enumeration method is always $0$ in my implementation.

[image]

Did anybody implement similar method before? Any tip for the implementation?

Thanks.

The algorithm taken from [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/097.pdf).

Comment: It sounds like something you just have to debug. You could print a message each iteration of the while loop to see how quickly it terminates, you could print the Gram-Schmidt matrix mu to see if it's properly filled etc.

Comment: (And being careful with indices can be tricky sometimes, both for programmers and for the people who wrote this pseudocode. Last week I implemented enumeration using exactly the pseudocode given at the very end of the Gama-Nguyen-Regev extreme pruning paper, and that worked correctly. So if you get stuck, you could also try that.)

Answer (score 0):

No clue what the issue is, there might be some typo or subtlety in your algorithm's exposition I missed and don't care to detect.

The `ENUM`  algorithm as described in one of your link's references is less elegantly exposited but works when implemented verbatim. Here is my implementation: https://github.com/enthdegree/lenum.m/